# Find the cell value based on other cells in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
          0            1    2
0  this           is  1.0
1    my         book  1.0
2  book         this  1.0
3    is           my  0.5
4    is  interesting  0.5
```

My data frame look like this but it is dynamic. So it can also look like

```
      0     1            2    3
0  this    is  interesting  0.5
1    is    my         book  1.0
2  this    is           my  0.5
3    my  book         this  1.0
4  book  this           is  1.0
```

Now I want to get the float values from the last column for giving the values of the first three columns values as a tuple. Like

```
("this","is") 
("this","is","interesting")
```

it should give me a value of 1.0 and 0.5 respectively. Plese help me to solve this problem.

Currently I am using this

```
row = df[(df["0"] == "is") & (df["1"] == "my")]
```

but it is not dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what u want, have a look and see if u can mod it to ur needs:

```
 f = ("this","is","interesting")

#condition checks if words can be found in the dataframe
#looks for rows that has all the words
#and converts to an array of True or False
cond = df.iloc[:,:-1].isin(f).all(axis=1).to_numpy()

#filter the dataframe, to get the values from the last column 
#where condition is True
#iloc works with an array or list of Booleans,
#it cannot reference a series label,
#hence then need to convert the cond to a list or array
df.iloc[cond,-1]

0    0.5
Name: 3, dtype: float64
```

of course, you can assign the result to a column ... but i am not sure if this is what u r after